# Firefox show "Server not found" all the time even after reinstalation

Tags: firefox

I use ubuntu 20.04 and I have got problem with firefox browser.
It always cannot download page and show "Server not found" all the time.
I tried chrome, it also doesn't work.
But Tor browser work.

I tried this https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/server-not-found-connection-problem#w_firefox-cannot-load-websites-but-other-browsers-can
, But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Is it all pages/sites or just one/a few?  Would try with another browser, to see if a firefox problem or something else.

Comment: All pages, I tryed chrome browser, it doesn't waork, but Tor browser work.

Comment: Looks like a network or an ISP problem.  Tor browser would hide page/site addresses from prying eyes.  Are you in an area where ISP/your overlords might play games with what you see?